# Reaching perfect fitness in a simple GA

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm

I was reading an introductory text on genetic algorithms and am currently stuck on an exercise problem. The individual in this problem is a 20 bit binary string and its fitness is simply the number of 1's in the string.

I performed mutation and crossover using fitness proportionate selection (roulette wheel approach is the term I think). However the question in the book asks to report at which generation does a perfectly fit string appear (all 1's in a row), and this never happens in my program even after the specified 20 iterations. I am unable to detect the problem.

Here is the code for the roulette wheel selection for two individuals to crossover (n_life denotes the number of individuals):

```
//selecting members for crossover (roulette wheel)
     int sum=0;
     int[] temp1 = new int[20];
     int[] temp2 = new int[20];
     int[][] result = new int[2][20];
     for(int i=0; i<n_life; i++){
      sum=sum+findex[i];     
     }

     int pointer = new Random().nextInt(sum); 
     int partsum=0;
     for(int b=0; b<n_life; b++){
         partsum=partsum+findex[b];
         if(partsum>pointer){for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
              temp2[i]=initial[b][i];
         }break;}
     }

      pointer = new Random().nextInt(sum); 
      partsum=0;
     for(int a=0; a<n_life; a++){
         partsum=partsum+findex[a];
         if(partsum>pointer){for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
             temp1[i]=initial[a][i];
         }break;}
     }
```

Finally the output for n_life = 10 is as follows. The first matrix is the initial population. The second matrix shows the fitness of all individuals in a particular generation. The third matrix is the final population.

```
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 

10  8   11  9   6   11  8   12  7   14  
10  8   11  9   9   11  8   12  11  14  
10  9   11  10  9   11  8   12  11  14  
10  14  11  10  14  11  8   12  11  14  
15  14  11  15  14  11  8   12  11  14  
15  14  15  15  14  15  8   12  11  14  
15  14  15  15  14  15  15  12  15  14  
15  14  15  15  14  15  15  12  15  14  
15  15  15  15  15  15  15  12  15  14  
15  15  15  15  15  15  15  13  15  16  
15  15  15  15  15  15  15  13  15  16  
16  16  15  15  15  15  15  13  15  16  
16  16  16  16  15  15  15  13  15  16  
16  16  16  16  15  15  15  13  15  16  
16  16  16  16  13  13  15  13  15  16  
16  16  16  16  13  13  15  13  15  16  
16  16  16  16  13  13  15  13  15  16  
16  16  16  16  16  16  15  13  15  16  
16  16  16  16  16  16  16  15  15  16  
16  16  16  16  16  16  16  15  15  16  

0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

The GA saturates at 16 but never reaches a fitness of 20. Can someone please point out the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running it several times? Since randomness is a factor in GA, it might be a random result. Also, do you use mutation somewhere?

Comment: I do use mutation with p=0.001 as specified in the question. And no matter how many times I run it, it never saturates to 20.

Comment: That p-value sounds very low for only 20 generations. Does it always end with the same population? If you look at the resulting population (3rd matrix), the empty columns appear where the sparse columns in the initial population appears. Are you limited to 20 generations?

Comment: The question mentions 20, I was thinking there might be some logic to that. Could you specify a more suitable number and the corresponding mutation probability?

Comment: The problem with GA's is that they are heuristic; they provide a solution which is "good enough" and that is all they can promise. So there seldom is a "correct" number to anything, you usually have to try and see what works. For generations, try running it until you reach the target fitness a couple of times and see how many generations that are required.

Comment: All right. But I was surprised that even in a simple GA such as this there is no guarantee for complete success.

Comment: The more time you give it, the higher is the chance of perfect success (you can see this relation yourself, I presume). But due to the randomness, there is always the off chance that a random event never occurs. If you've read discrete math, you might recognise a "proof of induction"

Comment: I performed 500 generations and mutation prob. = 0.01 and it worked. Thanks for the help!